# tkinter.Canvas.delete not working with nested functions

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, nested

As I am writing some `ctypes` compatible code, I need to use nested functions to modify a `tkinter.Canvas` object: I want to add and delete text (and later more graphics) in the `Canvas` object.

But anyhow it does not work and I got stuck.

This is my relevant code:

```
import tkinter as tk
class BasicGraphics(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        # ...
        self.cursor=0
        self.max_per_line = 50
        self.max_lines = 10
        self.h_diff = 15
        self.align_l = 90
        self.current_display = ["b" * self.max_per_line
                                for x in range(self.max_lines)]
        self.displayed_lines = []
        def start_x():
            self.root = tk.Tk()
            self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root,bg="black")
            self.canvas.pack()
            for line in self.current_display:
                self.displayed_lines.append(
                    self.canvas.create_text(
                        self.align_l,
                        self.h_diff * (self.cursor // 10 + 1),
                        text=line, fill="white"))
            print(self.canvas)
        def display_lines():
            self.canvas.delete("all")
            self.canvas.update()
            print(self.canvas)
            self.displayed_lines = []
            lineno = 1
            for line in self.current_display:
                self.displayed_lines.append(
                    self.canvas.create_text(
                        self.align_l,
                        lineno * self.h_diff * (self.cursor // 10 + 1),
                        text=line, fill="white"))
                lineno += 1
            self.canvas.pack() # tried pack and update
         def putc():
             pos = self.cursor
             h = pos//10
             w = pos%51
             ch = self.char_reg_read() # returns ord("a")
             self.current_display[h] = (self.current_display[h][0:w]
                                      + chr(ch)
                                      + self.current_display[h][w+1:])
             display_lines()
         start_x()
         putc()
         tk.mainloop()
    def char_reg_read(self):
        return ord("a")
```

but it does not even delete the "b"s.

As the `self` is inherited to the nested functions, it should work!

(I can post more code, if you need it)

Comment: What "it does not work" mean? What do you get? What do want? Reduce the code to a minimal example that causes the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Explain 'does not work'.   Code adds and deletes text before first update, so do not expect to see and deletion.  Read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Reason for nested functions not clear. Anyway, code does not work as `self.cursor` and `self.char_reg_read` are not defined.  The `canvas.pack` in `display lines is wrong.  Delete it.  The `lineno` variable is not used; delete it or use it.  Can use `current_display = ["b" * self.max_per_line] * self.max_lines` instead of list comp.

Comment: @MikeMüller as you might see, there should be displayed something like "abbbbbbbbbbbbbb" in the first row, but it is just "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb". __That__ is my problem!

Comment: @TerryJanReedy take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting about formatting. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I missed that:

from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

> create_text(position, **options) [#]
>
> Draws text on the canvas.
>
> position
> Text position, given as two coordinates. By default, the text is centered on this position. You can override this with the anchor option. For example, if the coordinate is the upper left corner, set the anchor to NW

So unluckily my "a" was not inside the canvas (and invisible), but it seemed, like the the text did show up properly.

The Problem is in fact not related to nested functions.